# jQuery code to YUI

Tags: jquery, yui

How would I translate this jQuery code into YUI3?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $.getJSON('file.php?path=<?php echo $_GET['path']; ?>&callback=?', function (data) {
            $("#filemanager-ajax").html('');
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                $("#filemanager-ajax").append('<a class="link" href="' + item.id + '"><div class="product" data="' + item.path + '"><img src="' + item.thumb + '" title="' + item.thumb + '" class="thumbnail"/><div class="title">' + item.name + '</div><div class="description"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Filesize:</strong> ' + item.size + '<div style="clear:both;height:8px;"></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;about ' + item.date + ' ago<div style="clear:both;height:8px;"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></a>');

             });
         });
     });
```

I know that in YUI it would look like this

```
YUI().use('json-parse', 'json-stringify', function (Y) {
    // JSON is available and ready for use. Add implementation
    // code here.
});
```

But how do I buld the JSON data into DIV element and output it via +item.id+, +item.thumb+ and so on

Comment: You should check out http://jsrosettastone.com/ a website that helps you translate YUI3 to and from jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the JSONP module:

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/jsonp/

Inside the callback, you can use:

```
var node = Y.one("#filemanager-ajax");
node.empty();

Y.each(data, function(item, i) {
  node.append(...);
});
```

Comment: Yes, when you include `callback=?` in `jQuery.getJSON` it's treated as JSONP. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp